# How can we fetch values from given input in Oracle using TRIM?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

'YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN' this is the input. I want fetch only 'SBINH13246802674' from the above input. This value is inserted to another column, that's why I am fetching that particular value. The condition is to only use the Oracle TRIM function. Is there possible to fetch that value using TRIM?

Comment: trim (leading 'YOUR UTR ' from 'YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN'); trim('TRAILING 'RTN' FROM 'SBINH13246802674 RTN');

Comment: trim takes only one character at a time for the purpose of trimming. Running your statement against my 11g gives me the error: ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character
30001. 00000 -  "trim set should have only one character"
*Cause:    Trim set contains more or less than 1 character. This is not
           allowed in TRIM function.

Comment: _"The condition is to only use the Oracle TRIM function"_, why? There are a lot better ways of doing this.

Comment: It depends; what does your other data look like? What is the format? Is it `YOUR UTR SBINH******** RTN`?

Comment: That value we fetch in a table and insert into another table.I need only that mentioned value only. This is only format.

Comment: -1: How is this supposed to be useful to anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

You could use below select query:

```
SELECT TRIM(' ' FROM TRIM(TRAILING 'R' FROM TRIM(TRAILING 'T' FROM TRIM(TRAILING 'N' FROM TRIM('R' FROM TRIM('T' FROM TRIM('U' FROM 
       TRIM(' ' FROM TRIM('R' FROM TRIM('U' FROM TRIM('O' FROM TRIM('Y' FROM 'YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN')))))))))))) DATA
FROM   DUAL;
```

This method uses repeated TRIMs which take out the unwanted string, one character at a time.

A better way to do this, however, is:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN', 'YOUR UTR '), ' RTN')
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use trim then use the below.

```
select rtrim(ltrim('YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN', 'YOUR UTR '), 'RTN') from dual;
```

If you need to do with any function then go for below considering you have all data with same format and length "YOUR UTR {DATA}"

```
select substr('YOUR UTR SBINH13246802674 RTN' , 10, 16) from dual;
```